# Infrequent Heroku H10 Crashes on a deployed Django app that otherwise runs smoothly

Tags: django, heroku

I've been doing a lot of searching, and everything I can find regarding this error are deployment issues, which isn't my issue in this case. About 20 times a day, I will get a notification (I use Logentries) of a crash following the pattern of:

```
21 Apr 2021 12:42:05.218340 <158>1 2021-04-21T16:42:04.670611+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=PUT path="/api/warehouse/updateclient/" host=<HOST> request_id=cf9e8b49-d05c-4fca-a8ea-e07c93b888ce fwd="<IP ADDRESS>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

I omitted sensitive information above.

Now a few things to note:

- This app is running successfully and 99% of requests to this route work correctly (it receives 50K+ requests a day).
- This specific route `/api/warehouse/updateclient/` is what is usually logged as the crash as it's the main endpoint for my API's client's updates (via Django Rest Framework), but this has also been logged on other routes as well, for example, an AJAX GET request on another route to update a status page.
- The Dyno does not reboot/restart during this, and all log entries before and after these crashes show the app to be running correctly (at the same endpoint), including the celery worker and the database updates. Often times within a second or so, it's responding to another request at the same endpoint.
- Response time and throughput of my app does not alter during these crashes according to Heroku metrics.

A saw some of the deployment issues were related to bad procfiles, so I'll copy mine here for reference:

```
web: gunicorn warehouse.wsgi
worker: celery --app=warehouse worker --loglevel info
```

Aside from logging several crashes a day, this doesn't seem to actually affect the ability for my application to run, aside from dropping a handful of requests a day and getting annoying emails. But what concerns me is if this is indicative of some underlying issue I'll encounter as I scale up. I can't seem to find any information on why this crash is occurring, specifically on a deployed app that otherwise appears to be running correctly.

Any insights/request for further information is welcomed, thank you for your time!

Comment: Anything jump out if you look at the performance metrics, e.g. high memory use? Are you using Sentry or similar to capture full tracebacks?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've been monitoring the metrics frequently when this happens, and there doesn't appear to be anything out of the ordinary. Memory remains the same (around 143 MB) and the response time doesn't spike.

I have Django set to email me when an unexpected error occurs with the full traceback, but as this crash is pre-my code, this handler is never reached. I'll check out Sentry though if it can cover more cases.

I did just notice that Heroku has put out this incident a couple hours ago: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2230

I have had one crash since then though.

Comment: Update: Have had several crashes since that incident so probably not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting support, these crashes appear to be related to service issues over the last few days:

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2230

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2231

Heroku has applied a patch to my app which has resolved these crashes.